# Out parameter is correctly assigned, but caller only sees a NULL. Clue?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, out-parameters

I have this procedure that gets dropped/created as part of a T-SQL script - the idea is to insert a *parent* record, and output its ID to the caller so that I can insert *children* records using that ID.

```
if exists (select * from sys.procedures where name = 'InsertCategory')
    drop procedure dbo.InsertCategory;
go

create procedure dbo.InsertCategory
     @code nvarchar(5)
    ,@englishName nvarchar(50)
    ,@frenchName nvarchar(50)
    ,@timestamp datetime = null
    ,@id int output
as begin

    if @timestamp is null set @timestamp = getdate();

    declare @entity table (_Id int, EntityId uniqueidentifier);
    declare @entityId uniqueidentifier;

    if not exists (select * from dwd.Categories where Code = @code)
    insert into dwd.Categories (_DateInserted, Code, EntityId) 
        output inserted._Id, inserted.EntityId into @entity
        values (@timestamp, @code, newid());
    else
        insert into @entity
        select _Id, EntityId from dwd.Categories where Code = @code;

    set @id = (select _Id from @entity);
    set @entityId = (select EntityId from @entity);

    declare @english int;
    set @english = (select _Id from dbo.Languages where IsoCode = 'en');

    declare @french int;
    set @french = (select _Id from dbo.Languages where IsoCode = 'fr');

    exec dbo.InsertTranslation @entityId, @english, @englishName, @timestamp;
    exec dbo.InsertTranslation @entityId, @french, @frenchName, @timestamp;

end
go
```

Then a little further down the script it's called like this:

```
declare @ts datetime;
set @ts = getdate();

declare @categoryId int;

exec dbo.InsertCategory 'C1', 'Category1', 'Catégorie1', @ts, @categoryId;
exec dbo.InsertSubCategory 'SC1', @categoryId, 'Description (EN)', 'Description (FR)', @ts
```

When I *debug* the script and step through line by line, I can see that `dbo.InsertCategory` correctly assigns the `@id` out parameter, which the script sees as `@categoryId` - the problem is that `@categoryId` is always `null`, and so I'm not getting anything inserted into `dwd.SubCategories`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mention the `@categoryId` parameter as `OUTPUT` while calling the procedure else it is not going to return the value. Call the procedure like this

```
exec dbo.InsertCategory 'C1', 'Category1', 'Catégorie1', @ts, @categoryId OUTPUT;
```

**Example**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Procd (@a INT, @b INT output)
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT @b = @a
  END

DECLARE @new INT

EXEC Procd 1,@new 
SELECT @new -- NULL

EXEC Procd 1,@new OUTPUT 
SELECT @new -- 1
```

Comment: Ah! I knew it had to be a tiny little thing! Thanks!